# null parameter in POST request

Tags: jquery, servlets

I'm going to use jQuery Ajax to post requests:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
               url: "/UsersCounter", 
               type: "POST", 
               cache: false, 
               data: {"emailAddr": "example@domain.com"}, 
               dataType: "text", 
               contentType: "application/json"
         });
```

and server side I have a simple servlet to handle http requests:

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

   String x=req.getParameter("emailAddr");
   ...
  }
```

In browsers parameter of `emailAddr` is visible in POST requests but value of `x` is `null` in the servlet. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: I would think dataType: "json" is more fitting?

Comment: application/json will convert that data into payload instead of query parameters

Answer (score -2):

Every thing fine except this line

```
  data: {"emailAddr": "example@domain.com"},
```

"emailAddr" should not be in quotes, instead above line use following syntax

```
 data: {emailAddr: "example@domain.com"},
```

I think Now this will work fine

beside this you can use datatype application/json then in data you can use json.stringify to avoid simple mistakes before calling asynchronous request to server.